# How would you jerry-rig an android phone for continuous autonomous operation?

Tags: microcontroller, automotive, gps, gsm, android

I want to use an android phone as dash-cam with GPS tracking capabilities.
It is supposed to run 24 hours a day, 365 days a year.

If the phone / app hangs, the user cannot be expected to troubleshoot it. (This is the most important requirement). So I want to have a self recovery mechanism to recover from software glitches.

I am thinking of adding a MOSFET between the positive contact on battery and the corresponding pin on the phone. The MOSFET would be controlled by a micro-controller which acts as a watchdog. Additionally, the micro controller may also pull up/down the POWER-ON pin on the phone to turn on the phone.

I am concerned that the device's life could shorten due to exposure to higher than normal levels of heat and vibration. But apart from that I don't see any reason for this to not work.

Has anyone tried doing something like this before? What are some mistakes one can avoid?

Comment: Jerry-rig? Nope, we don't jerry-rig here.

Comment: What is wrong about having an off the shelf dash cam with an off the shelf GPS logger, and then sync both using the a timestamp?

Comment: You probably don't want to spend time building this around a device on which you can't use a custom built-from-source Android and Linux Kernel install.  On one where you can, you might look at things like enabling a hardware watchdog in the CPU, and servicing it from relatively high level code under Android.  Or put the watchdog in your external power-button-pusher microcontroller.  But do think about the power source - perhaps you can use a battery emulator, or perhaps you have one of the devices that will run from USB power with the battery missing.

Comment: While Android devices certainly are cheap (as low as $10 retail) note however that Android phone GPS's may not work well (or potentially even at all) without a data connection.

Comment: @ox6d64 They can't run user programs, lack cellular/Wi-Fi radios, sensors and a good API to put them to use.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Could you post a link to $10 retail android phone? At that price, I've only seen GSM Feature phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I'd be careful not to underestimate is how hot the inside of a car can get. I've done some previous design work on GPS systems that were typically mounted under the passenger seat of a car and during summer 40 - 45 °C days the internal temperature sensor would often read around 80 °C and stay there for a significant amount of the day.

That exceeds the maximum recommended discharge / discharge temperatures of Li-Ion batteries and while many phones might be OK with it I've owned phones that won't work without a battery present presumably because they rely on it to meet short peak current demands. If parts of the battery protection circuit cut-out under high temperature it might cause problems, of course hard to know with a consumer device where you won't be privy to the exact design so you'd really need to test that side of things.

Another issue you may have is determining when the device needs a hard power reset. Software lock-ups using a watchdog are easy enough but for example my Nexus 5 seems to lose a data connection every month or two and seems to need a reboot. In normal use I can determine whether I'd expect a data connection in the location and manually restart when convenient, but doing it automatically you might end up in a situation where you're restarting often when the only real problem is the lack of signal or other connectivity issue.

In general I'd say the idea is plausible but while the upside is having very low up-front development costs the downside to using COTS consumer devices is you'll need some extensive testing to see how it performs under a variety of conditions and try a few different devices. For temperature related tests a regular oven / temperature probe does the job pretty well but for some other aspects there won't really be an alternative to long-term testing of multiple devices.

Of course another disadvantage is that software / hardware engineering changes in new revisions of the phone in the future may cause changes in performance that you don't have control over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The watchdog need not be dumb. For example - it could talk to the phone via USB and not reset the phone for such problems. Yeah temperature, and other environmental factors are indeed a concern. But there is a big prize at the other end if these problems are sorted out. Thanks again.